# how to fetch data in 3 tables using with relation in laravel

Tags: laravel, relation

I want to fetch data from three tables. the table is named as Student admission and course. In my query, I fetch student data and admission data using the below query

$student = Student::with('student_fees')->with('admissions')->get();

and I also want course table data, but the course table data are related to admission table. how can I fetch course table data using this query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested eager loading
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading

Assume that you defined the relation with the Laravel convention in each Model Class. You can call the nested eager loading like following:

```
$student = Student::with(['student_fees', 'admissions', 'admissions.course'])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = DB::table('Student')->join('admissions', 'student.id', '=', 'admissions.student_id')->join('course', 'course.id', '=', 'admissions.course_id')->select('Student.*', 'Student.name', 'course.name')->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins - this could help you